# Comment Count Function to Var?

Tags: javascript, variables, comments, html

```
   fyre.conv.load({}, [conversationInfo], function(widget) {
    widget.on('commentCountUpdated', function(data)) {
              //Data here
    });
}};
```

via Livefyre
How do I turn the data result to a var?

Comment: `data` is a variable.

Comment: so I could document.write(data)?

Comment: No, because it's asynchronous, so it would overwrite the entire page with the new content. You could, however, select an element and set its `innerHTML`. Of course, that relies on `data` being valie HTML, and not something like an array (which would result in `[object Array]` being printed)

Comment: It's just an integer.

Comment: Could you please help me turn (data) printed in to simple text.

Comment: @MilPro widget.on('commentCountUpdated', function(data) { $('#comment-count').text(data); });